# Integral of square of function is equal to integral of odd part squared plus integral of even part squared

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, signal-processing, even-and-odd-functions

This is an exercise from Oppenheim's course on signals and systems.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x_e^2(t)dt + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x_o^2(t)dt $$

where $x_e(t)$ and $x_o(t)$ are respectively the even and odd parts of $x(t)$

The way I did it was

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x_e^2(t)dt + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x_o^2(t)dt +  2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x_o(t)x_e(t)dt$$

Then
$$  x_o(t)x_e(t) = \frac 12 [x(t) - x(-t)] *  \frac 12 [x(t) + x(-t)] = \frac 14 [x^2(t) - x^2(-t)]$$

$$  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x_o(t)x_e(t)dt = \frac 14  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2(t)dt - \frac 14 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2(-t)dt$$

Then using u substitution (and this is the part where I'm not sure what I did makes sense, namely can I flip the infinities by putting a minus signal before the integral? I know it works for definite integrals without infinities but I'm confused about integrals with infinities)

$$\frac 14  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2(t)dt - \frac 14 \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}-x^2(y)dy = \frac 14  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2(t)dt + \frac 14 \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}x^2(y)dy =  \frac 14  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2(t)dt - \frac 14 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2(y)dy = 0$$

Comment: Also, this is meta but when I added the tag signal processing it told me to check https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ Was this the correct place to post?

Comment: Your work looks correct to me. You can try simple examples to check your work.